# no hashtag in url jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

below is an accordion code which works perfectly. i don't want to use hashtag as it breaks our current sites. is there a way to use a no hashtag url with accordion?
I tried using "?" however, it didn't work when access the accordion using a url? is this even possible?

so the idea is to be able to open the accordion when i have a url like this:

From: test.html#Link1 To: test.html?Link1, it doesn't have to be question mark, i was just trying it out to see, it could be anything other than hashtag. thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

  var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({active: false, collapsible: true}),
      hashId = 0;

    if (window.location.hash) {
      $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
        var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_');
        this.id = txt;
        if (txt === window.location.hash.slice(1)) {
          hashId = i;
        }
      });

      $accordion.accordion({
        active: hashId,
        animate: true,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        collapsible: true,
        create: function( event, ui ) {
          $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
            $(this).before('<a class="accordion-link link" data-index="' + i + '" href="?' + this.id + '"></a>');
          });
          $accordion.find('.accordion-link').click(function(){
            $accordion.accordion( "option", "active", $(this).data('index') );
          });
        }
    });
    }
  });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="?link1">Link1</a></h3>
<div>content</div>

<h3><a href="?link2">Link2</a></h3>
<div>content</div>
</div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but # is not a hashtag, it's just a hash, pound or number sign.

Comment: @Steve you get the idea, hash, pound, i guess i used hashtag because of twitter says hashtag, thanks for the correction, so pound, number sign, etc. i don't want this to be the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the url with the format `test.html?section=Link1`. You just need to stop using the hash, and extract the queryString parameter [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). The resulting code would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  }

  $(function() {

    var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({active: false, collapsible: true}),
      hashId = 0,
      section = getParameterByName('section');

    if (section) {
      $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
        var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_');
        this.id = txt;
        if (txt === section) {
          hashId = i;
        }
      });

      $accordion.accordion({
        active: hashId,
        animate: true,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        collapsible: true,
        create: function( event, ui ) {
          $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
            $(this).before('<a class="accordion-link link" data-index="' + i + '" href="?' + this.id + '"></a>');
          });
          $accordion.find('.accordion-link').click(function(){
            $accordion.accordion( "option", "active", $(this).data('index') );
          });
        }
    });
    }
  });
        </script>
```